# Multiple LEDs and using and input button

Tags: c, microprocessors

I am really stuck on part a and b for problem 1 below. I am really confused on how to change the multiply and divide functions to change pins/LED’s, using the << and >> functions instead.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Multiple LEDs and using and input button

1. Modify the C program:

a. Instead of using the multiply and divide functions to change pins/LED’s, use the << and >> functions. References: Deitel and Deitel “C, How to Program and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C

b. Change the clock frequency in the program to 1 MHz and make the on/off time of each LED .1 seconds. This should make the rotation visibly faster. (Remember to change the _XTAL_FREQ value since this is used for the __delay_ms() function built into XC8)

Devices:

Low Pin Count board (16F1829 on board) and 44-Pin Demo Board are both on same backboard. (You only use the 16F1829 for this lab.)

PICKIT 3 programmer with USB cable

MPLAB X (I used v3.00 but a different version may be on lab computers))

Microchip XC8 C Compiler User Manual

PIC16F1829 Data Sheet

PICkit 3 User’s Guide

Low Pin Count Board User Guide

“C How to Program” Deitel, Pearson/Prentice-Hall (Any edition)

Internet Browser Search Engine for research (Google, Bing, etc)
upload_2018-9-5_23-27-22.png

The code is below.

```
/*
LEDs on for approximately 0.5 sec.
PIC: 16F1829 Enhanced Mid-Level
Compiler: XC8 v1.34
IDE: MPLABX v3.00 */

#include <pic16f1829.h> //Not required but this is the reference used by "C" for names and location on uC
#include <htc.h> //refers on HiTech C, Microchip purchased HiTech
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000 //Used by the XC8 delay_ms(x) macro
#define switch PORTAbits.RA2 // Can use RA2 instead of PORTAbit.RA2 to define pin attached to switch

//instead of saying PORTAbits.RA2 each time
//config bits for the PIC16F1829
#pragma config FOSC=INTOSC, WDTE=OFF, PWRTE=OFF, MCLRE=OFF, CP=OFF, CPD=OFF, BOREN=ON, CLKOUTEN=OFF, IESO=OFF, FCMEN=OFF
#pragma config WRT=OFF, PLLEN=OFF, STVREN=OFF, LVP=OFF

//Initialization subroutine
void initialize(void) {
    ANSELC=0; //All pins of Port C are digital I/O
    ANSA2=0; //switch pin, RA2, is digital IO
    TRISA2 = 1; //switch is an input
    TRISC = 0; //all pins of Port C are outputs
    OSCCON = 0b01101000; // 4 MHz
}

unsigned char i1; //only need 4 bits to count to 16. unsigned character variable is 8 bits long

// Here is main(). There are many ways to do this 4-pin (LED) sequence
void main(void)
{
    initialize();
    i1=1; //Start the main program with the variable =1. Could have done this during its definition

    while (1) //runs continuously until MCU is shut off
    {

        if (switch==1) //Button not pressed pin at 5V
        { i1=1; }
        while (switch==1) //Button not pressed
        {
            PORTC=i1; //Note that writing to PORTC writes to LATC
            __delay_ms(500);
            i1=i1*2;
            if (i1==16)
            { i1=1; }
        }

        if (switch==0) //Button pressed pin at ground
        { i1=8; }
        while (switch==0) //Button pressed
        {
            PORTC=i1;
            __delay_ms(500);
            i1=i1/2;
            if (i1==0)
            { i1=8; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please start by formatting your code. Empty lines and indentation might not matter to the compiler, but it does for humans attempting to read your code.

Comment: Here is the multiply code:
i1=i1*2;
Here is the divide code:
i1=i1/2;

completely lost on where to start on changing this to use << and >> functions to change pins/LED’s.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add info, instead of hiding it in comments.

Comment: Thank you for attempting some indentation on your code, but it only helps if it is consistent.

Comment: Not intending to sound mean here, my goal is to help you learn to help yourself. 
 Did you read the link you posted about operators? Did you scroll down to the table with the bit shift operators?  Did you then click that link and read the article about the shift operators?  After reading the article did you [make a small program](https://ideone.com/G829Cp) (otherwise known as a [mcve]) where you could use the shift operators and print out what the results are to help you understand what they do? Following those kinds of steps will help you greatly as a developer.

Comment: I ran into a hint from a question. 
1 << 1 means:
0000000000000001 changes to 0000000000000010
1 << 8 means:

0000000000000001 changes to 0000000100000000
It's a bit shift operation. For every 1 on the right, you can think of yourself as multiplying the value on the left by 2. So, 2 << 1 = 4 and 2 << 2 = 8. This is much more efficient than doing 1 * 2.
Also, you can do 4 >> 1 = 2 (and 5 >> 1 = 2 since you round down) as the inverse operation.

Comment: I am really new to coding so I was lost by a lot of this. I am still trying to fiqure out how to incorporate this into the code.

Comment: not sure if this is right. i1=i1*2; would equal i1=i1*4>>1; and would this also be correct? i1=i1/2; would make i1=i1/4>>1;

Comment: or since i1=1 on first part then  i1=i1*2 would be  i1=4>>1 . then for the second part for i1=i1/2. since i1=8 then it would be  i1=2 << 1;

Comment: It sounds like the goal of the assignment is to get you to completely replace the multiplication and division by just using the shift operators.  Look back at your first comment after my comment. "For every 1 on the right, you can think of yourself as multiplying the value on the left by 2". So how could that information help you to replace the multiplication in this statement `i1 = i1 * 2`?

Comment: I believe i grasp this now. thanks for being patient with me as learn this.
So i1=i1*2 would then be i1=i1<<1 (the value of i1 would be shifted to the left in the binary code by 1 therefore multiplying it by 2.)
then i1=i1/2 would be i1=i1>>1 (the value of i1 would be shifted to the right in the binary code by 1 therefore dividing it by 2.)

Comment: Exactly! Everyone learns different, for me, making a sample program and trying it out really helps me to understand something (or shows me that I am not understanding something ;) )  [Here](https://ideone.com/LKed2b) is an example showing multiplying/dividing compared with shifting.

Answer (score 1):

> a. Instead of using the multiply and divide functions to change
>   pins/LED’s, use the << and >> functions. References: Deitel and Deitel
>   “C, How to Program and
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C

Left shift `value << n` is integer multiplication of value by 2^n or value*(2^n)

Right shift `value >> n` is integer division of value by 2^n or value/(2^n))

When you have some `var` and you use one of the shift operators, you are taking the value of whatever `var` is and shifting the binary digits (bits) that represent it's value to the left or the right.

A basic example of this:

```
uint8_t var = 1; //0b00000001 in binary
var <<= 1; //var is now 0b00000010, that is 1*(2^1) or 2
var >>= 1; //var is now 0b00000001, that is 2/(2^1) or 1
```

There is a huge caveat for using the shift operator and that is that whenever you shift bits you are filling 0s in from the opposite direction that you are shifting so you have to pay attention to the integer size.

```
uint8_t var = 1;
var <<= 4; //var is now 0b00010000, 4 zeros filled in on the right
var = 1;
var <<= 8; //var is now 0b00000000, because 8 zeros were filled in on the right!
```

Now with regard to how you use this to manipulate the pins on a microcontroller, you would take some variable that increments or decrements and shift left or right by that variable and assign the resulting value to the register in the module that controls that pin, which in this case is the `PORTx` module. In your code that would look like this:

```
    if (switch == 1) //Button not pressed pin at 5V
    {

        i1 = 0; //initialize to 0

    }
    while (switch == 1) //Button not pressed
    {

        PORTC = (1 << i1++); //set will set just one pin at a time, the first will be pin 0, the next pin 1, and so on

        __delay_ms(500);

        if (i1 == 8){

            i1 = 0; //reset variable

        }

    }

    if (switch == 0) //Button pressed pin at ground
    {

        i1 = 0; //initialize to 0

    }
    while (switch == 0) //Button pressed
    {
        PORTC = (0x80 >> i1++); //this will set 1 pin at a time, the first will be pin 7, the next will be pin 6, and so on

        __delay_ms(500);

        if (i1 == 8)
        {
            i1 = 0; //reset variable
        }

    }
```

> b. Change the clock frequency in the program to 1 MHz and make the
>   on/off time of each LED .1 seconds. This should make the rotation
>   visibly faster. (Remember to change the _XTAL_FREQ value since this is
>   used for the __delay_ms() function built into XC8)

This portion of your code:

```
OSCCON = 0b01101000; // 4 MHz
```

Actually configures the frequency of the oscillator used by the microcontroller for its clock signal. However, it is important for you to know the source of that clock signal, which according to the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41440A.pdf) is controlled by Configuration Word 1. This is set in the `#pragma config FOSC=INTOSC` portion of your code.

To obtain 1 MHz you will want to change that line to this:

```
OSCCON = 0b01011000; // 1 MHz
```

This is found in the OSCCON register description in the datasheet.

The `__delay_ms` function uses the _XTAL_FREQ to calculate a delay which is why you are being told to change this line of your code:

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
```

To this

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 1000000
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please upvote my answer if you feel that it answered your question.